# Sending emails using AWS SES v2 with attachments

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, email, amazon-ses

I was trying to build a spring boot api to send emails using AWS SES v2 but I am stuck as to how to send the email in the last stages using the client of SES v2. For SES version 1, we could make the RawMessage object and then build the message using `SendRawEmailRequest` and then finally send it using the client (`client.sendEmail(rawEmailRequest);`), but for v2, unfortunately, the client does not take the `SendRawEmailRequest`'s object as a parameter and I do not see any documentation as to how to make it happen. It would be of great help if someone could help me out with it.

This is the link for the AWS code example from AWS website which I have taken as a reference:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/usecases/creating_dynamodb_web_app/src/main/java/com/example/services/SendMessages.java

below here is my code to send an email with attachment using SES v2 client:

```
@Override
public EmailContent sendemailAttachment() throws MessagingException, IOException {

    SesV2Client client = awssesConfig.getAmazonSESCient();

    final String sender = "dibyanshu.chatterjee@phoenix.edu";
    final String recipient = "alpeshkumar.patel@phoenix.edu";
    final String subject = "SES test";
    final String bodyText = "Testing out SES";
    final String bodyHTML = "";
    final String fileLocation = "C:\\Users\\dchatter\\Downloads\\vedic.csv";

    File theFile = new File(fileLocation);
    byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(theFile.toPath());

    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties());

    // Create a new MimeMessage object.
    MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

    // Add subject, from and to lines.
    message.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(sender));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipient));

    // Create a multipart/alternative child container.
    MimeMultipart msgBody = new MimeMultipart("alternative");

    // Create a wrapper for the HTML and text parts.
    MimeBodyPart wrap = new MimeBodyPart();

    // Define the text part.
    MimeBodyPart textPart = new MimeBodyPart();
    textPart.setContent(bodyText, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

    // Define the HTML part.
    if (!bodyHTML.equals("")){
        MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(bodyHTML, "text/html; charset=UTF-8");
        msgBody.addBodyPart(htmlPart);
    }


    // Add the text and HTML parts to the child container.
    msgBody.addBodyPart(textPart);


    // Add the child container to the wrapper object.
    wrap.setContent(msgBody);

    // Create a multipart/mixed parent container.
    MimeMultipart msg = new MimeMultipart("mixed");

    // Add the parent container to the message.
    message.setContent(msg);

    // Add the multipart/alternative part to the message.
    msg.addBodyPart(wrap);

    // Define the attachment.
    MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataSource fds = new ByteArrayDataSource(fileContent, "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    att.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));

    String reportName = "vedic.csv";
    att.setFileName(reportName);

    // Add the attachment to the message.
    msg.addBodyPart(att);

    try {
        System.out.println("Attempting to send an email through Amazon SES " + "using the AWS SDK for Java...");

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.office365.com");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");

        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props);
        mailSession.setDebug(true);

        Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.office365.com ",587,"dibyanshu.chatterjee@phoenix.edu","Neel@ndakash27");
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO));
        transport.close();
        System.out.println("email sent");

        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        message.writeTo(outputStream);

        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(outputStream.toByteArray());

        byte[] arr = new byte[buf.remaining()];
        buf.get(arr);

        SdkBytes data = SdkBytes.fromByteArray(arr);

        RawMessage rawMessage = RawMessage.builder()
                .data(data)
                .build();

        SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = SendRawEmailRequest.builder()
                .rawMessage(rawMessage)
                .build();
        client.sendEmail(rawEmailRequest);
```

Comment: the SMTP properties can be ignored as that was just something I was trying out. I am having an error in the client.sendEmail(rawEmailRequest); statement.

Answer (score 1):

SES SDK V1 code:

```
RawMessage rawMessage = RawMessage.builder().data(data).build();
SendRawEmailRequest rawEmailRequest = SendRawEmailRequest.builder().rawMessage(rawMessage).build();

SendRawEmailResponse resp = sesClient.sendRawEmail(rawEmailRequest);
```

SES SDK V2 code:

```
SendEmailRequest emailRequest = SendEmailRequest.builder()
        .content(EmailContent.builder().raw(rawMessage).build())
        .build();

SendEmailResponse resp = sesV2Client.sendEmail(emailRequest);
```

Other parts of the raw email sending code works same way and there is no 10MB limitation for attachments any more, 40MB is the limit, but anyways I don't recommend sending attachments that are more than 18MB in size.

Comment: There is no "builder" on SendEmailRequest.  I'm using current
AWSSDK.SimpleEmailV2, Version=3.3.0.0